# IOS react-native app build successfully but stuck in installing

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

After implementation of firebase my react native firebase app is building successfully but it stuck in installing, I'm not understanding what's the issue.

Its my terminal console print

info Opening the app on iOS...
info Found Xcode workspace "spengucomputercourse.xcworkspace"
info Found booted iPhone 14 Pro
info Launching iPhone 14 Pro
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace spengucomputercourse.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme spengucomputercourse -destination id=27E9C6B7-F349-442A-84CB-8A6F8547FD27")
success Successfully built the app
info Installing "/Users/englishmuni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/spengucomputercourse-hcuypjzekimcstfdcorltqjfmrtt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/spengucomputercourse.app on iPhone 14 Pro"

Here is my podfile file

```
 pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true

require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'spengucomputercourse' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
  
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
   
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,

    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )
  target 'spengucomputercourseTests' do
    inherit! :complete

  end
  post_install do |installer|
  
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

Here you can find my AppDelegate.m file

```
#import <Firebase.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
  self.moduleName = @"spengucomputercourse";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```